# Passing event listener a reference to "self";

Tags: javascript

I just wanted to know if its acceptable to save a reference to "this" as a variable and then use that in an eventListener. If not can someone please inform as to the best practice for passing reference to a different context in javascript.

Example:

```
someListener(){
    let self = this; //referencing this class
    
    someObject.addEventListener("click"), function(){
       //some magic applied here
       self.someArray.push("something");
    }
}
```

I cant think of another way to reference a different context (that of the class that the event listener belongs to) when dealing with an event.

Thanks

Comment: If you pass the event listener an arrow function then `self` is not needed.

Comment: But this approach is also acceptable and widely used in pre-ES6 codes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fine, and highly idiomatic ES5 (using the name `that` is also common).

ES6 gives us [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which use a lexical `this` instead of having their own.

```
someListener(){
    someObject.addEventListener("click"), () => {
       //some magic applied here
       this.someArray.push("something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you I will have a read about this.

Comment: this does not seem to work for on-change events.
`obj.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log(this);// shows window
    })`

Comment: @Brad — That would be because at the point where you put that code `this` is `window`. If you changed the whole line of code to `alert(this === window)` then it would be `true`. It has nothing to do with the type of event.

Answer (score 4):

Before [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) were introduced, this was a common way among javascript developers but now you can get around this problem using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
someListener(){
    someObject.addEventListener("click"), () => {
       this.someArray.push("something");
    }
}
```

Using an arrow function solves this problem because arrow functions do not get their own binding of `this`. They get their value from the enclosing scope, which in your case is the local scope of `someListener` function.

Comment: I wish I would of went on stack yesterday to find this out lmao...thank you sir